# Why Mockito can't mock a generic parameter type with number type in Kotlin?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, kotlin

We're moving our project to the Kotlin language. We decided to start from tests but faced with some strange behavior.

Here is our test case:

**Service.java**

```
public final class Service {
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public Service(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public long check() {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table", Long.class);
    }
}
```

**JavaTest.java** (works fine)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public final class JavaTest {
    @Mock
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private Service testSubject;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //given
        when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(anyString(), eq(Long.class))).thenReturn(1L);

        //when
        long result = testSubject.check();

        //then
        assertThat(result, is(1L));
    }
}
```

**KotlinTest.kt** (not working)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class KotlinTest {
    @Mock
    private lateinit var jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate

    @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var testSubject: Service

    @Test
    fun test() {
        //given
        `when`(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(anyString(), eq(Long::class.java))).thenReturn(1L)

        //when
        val result = testSubject.check()

        //then
        assertThat(result, `is`(1L))
    }
}
```

Kotlin test fails with NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at c.i.Service.check(Service.java:13)
    at c.i.KotlinTest.test(KotlinTest.kt:30)
```

Also, MockitoHint says:

```
[MockitoHint] KotlinTest.test (see javadoc for MockitoHint):
[MockitoHint] 1. Unused... -> at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:500)
[MockitoHint]  ...args ok? -> at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:500)
```

Can someone describe what is happening here? I'm quite new to Kotlin and might miss something.

Dependencies version: Kotlin 1.1.3-2, Mockito 2.7.19

Comment: Try to remove `lateinit` from variables declaration.

Comment: @talex got the same errors

Comment: I can get this to work with this: 

   `\`when\`(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(anyString(), eq(java.lang.Long::class.java))).thenReturn(java.lang.Long(1L)) `.

I think the reason is because the argument matcher thinks `java.lang.Long.class != kotlin.Long.class` so provides an un-mocked method.

Comment: Using mockito-kotlin, it's slightly less nasty:  `\`when\`(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(anyString(), argThat<Class<Long>> { this == java.lang.Long::class.java })).thenReturn(1L)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use the [KClass#javaObjectType](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-object-type.html) instead, for example:

```
// use java.lang.Long rather than long ---v
when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(anyString(), eq(Long::class.javaObjectType)))
                   .thenReturn(1L)
```

> **Why** does this error occurs?

This is because `Long::class.java` returns a primitive type `long` class rather than a `java.lang.Long` class. For example:

```
println(Long::class.java.name) // long
println(Long::class.javaObjectType.name) // java.lang.Long

println(Long::class.javaObjectType == Long::class.java) 
//                                 ^--- false: their class are different
```

The **mocked** method parameters matcher is `[String, Class<`**`long`**`>]` in the Kotlin test code.
When mockito can not find the **matched** method `[String, Class<`**`Long`**`>]` for **mocking** in Java `Service` class, then it will return a **default value** for the **mismatched** `getForObject` method call, but the return type of the `getForObject` method is `Object` - so a **null** value is returned by default.

However, the return type of the `check` method is `long`, and the JVM tries **unboxing** `null` into the primitive type **long** in your `Service` class -  which causes a `NullPointerException` to be thrown. For example:

```
when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(anyString(), eq(Long::class.java)))
                   .thenReturn(1L)

assertEquals(1, jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("<any>", Long::class.java))  
//                           ^--- matched: return 1 

assertNull(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("<any>", Long::class.javaObjectType)) 
//                      ^--- mismatched: return null

testSubject.check()
//          ^--- throws NullPointerException
```

**IF** you will replace the usage of the `Long` class with `long.class` - you will also get the same error. For example:

```
//      use long.class rather than Long.class ---v
when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(anyString(), eq(long.class))).thenReturn(1L);


 //                      v--- matched: return 1L
assertThat(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("<any>", long.class), is(1L));

try {
    //                        v--- mismatched: return null
    long value = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("<any>", Long.class);
    //   ^--- throws NullPointerException when doing unboxing operation  
    fail();
} catch (NullPointerException expected) {
    assertTrue(true);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not good at English, so I wish you can understand the original problem, :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @ninja Not at all.